# Add exception trace from angular to app insight

Tags: angular, azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to write exceptions from angular to azure app insight.
If i do JSON.stringify(error), exception is getting recorded. But  i don't want to stringify the error instead can we save error without stringify?

Working code:

```
  let exception: IExceptionTelemetry = {
   exception: new Error(JSON.stringify(error)),
 };
 this.appInsights.trackException(exception);
```

I tried below coded without stringify but it doesn't work i.e no errors are logged in azure appInsight:

```
 let exception: IExceptionTelemetry = {
  exception: error
};
this.appInsights.trackException(exception);

 OR
let exception: IExceptionTelemetry = {
   exception: {
     name: error.name,
     message: error.message,
     stack: error.stack
  }
};
this.appInsights.trackException(exception);
```

I am using @microsoft/applicationinsights-web ~2.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work with App Insights, but observing your example i think you should try with one more nesting level in 'exception', something like this:

```
const {message, name, stack} = error;

let exception: IExceptionTelemetry = {
  exception: {
    message: {message, name, stack},
    ...
  },
};
```

Also want to highlight 2 things here:

1. if the `error` is actual instance of `Error` class (not a custom object), than `JSON.stringify(error) === "{}"`, because 'message' and 'stack' are not enumerable fields in 'Error'... So when you dealing with fields of an Error, you have to access them implicitly.
2. In this case App Insight will receive an object instead of stringified object. Is it correct?

*update*
I found this in docs:

```
appInsights.trackException({exception: new Error('some error')});
```

So maybe this will work:

```
const {message, name, stack} = error;

let exception: IExceptionTelemetry = {
  exception: new Error(message),
};
```

Comment: I tried with the first approach it didn't worked. In your second approach you are doing new Error(message), this is already working for me. But i also want to log trace  and not just message.

Comment: But did you noticed difference between ways of building error? 
when you do JSON.stringify(error) - you will get exact this string `"{}"`, but when you do like this

`const {message, name, stack} = error; return  {message, name, stack};`
you will get proper object. Some kind of serialization.